# Unable to find and click on URL by using the "By PartialLinkText" in Selenium Web Driver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using following code to find and click on a URL. I have multiple links on a webpage. I need to find my desired URL and click on it. To accomplish the task, I am storing my partial string in 'urlname' variable and using it in below example:

`driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(urlname)).Click();`

But the above code does not do anything. Its not even finding the element and not clicking on it. Kindly help on this.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table xmlns:downloader="http://schemas.niku.com/java/com.niku.dms.web.ZipPageDownloader" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="tableGridList" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="TableGridList"><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col"><a href="javascript:checkAllOver('dms.fileManager');"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/IcoCheckAll.gif" border="0" alt="Check All" title="Check All"></a></td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" colspan="3" align="center" scope="col">Name</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" align="center" scope="col">&nbsp;</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Size</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Type</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Status</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Modified</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Actions</td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5697033&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">Great India's place</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">9/26/15 8:27 PM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5697033" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5697033')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5687045&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">India's silver gold awards</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">8/6/15 12:04 PM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5687045" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5687045')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5693965&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">India's Gold awards</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">9/8/15 10:02 AM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5693965" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5693965')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5691948&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">Awards night - India</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">8/28/15 7:30 AM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5691948" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5691948')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to click on a link "India's Gold awards". I have stored "Gold awards" string in the variable 'urlname'.

Comment: Please show us the page and the value of 'urlname'

Comment: @AndrewRegan I have updated my question, can you please see to it and let me know the solution.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me. Are you waiting for the page to load before you send the request? Any errors?

Comment: Yes everything working fine except this. My script stuck over here at this step. Nothing happens.